# URL method does not work on 3.1.3 (generated by Core Data)

Tags: iphone

I have some issues with getting my app running on my iPhone 1G 3.1.3.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyTest.sqlite"];    
    ...
```

This is copied from the code generated by xcode when I use Core Data. How can I fix the URLByAppendingPathComponent method to something that works? Should I store the path returned by applicationDocumentsDirectory-method and make a new NSURL with that path + MyTest.sqlite or is there a better way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [self applicationDocumentsDirectory] is an NSURL

NSString *docsDirectoryString = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] absoluteString];
NSString *storePathString = [docsDirectoryString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyTest.sqlite"];

NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:storePathString];

Comment: Answer to comment on question: Yes thank you, sorry I forgot to accept it.

Comment: When I tried this, the resulting URL started with file:/ instead of file:// like it should.  I think this is causing problems.